# Как получить все дочерние элементы при парсинге с помощью DiDOM

Tags: php, парсер

Сайт-донор имеет такой вот блок со списком:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задача состоит в том, чтобы вытащить все элементы **li.spisok**, но так как на сайте может быть много различных элементов **ul**, включающих в себя элементы **li.spisok** требуется для начала вытащить элемент **ul.container**, а у него потом взять дочек. Вот код, которым я это делаю:

```
require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');

use DiDom\Document;


$url = 'https://svmed.spb.ru/spisok/';
$file = file_get_contents($url);

$document = new Document($file, false);
$ul = $document->find('.container')[0];
echo $ul;
$all_li = $ul->children();
```

Проблема в том, что при выводе найденного элемента **$ul** выводится лишь его первый элемент **li** и поиск по всем его дочерним элементам становится невозможен, хотя по идее должно быть выведено все содержимое блока **ul.container**. Почему так?

Comment: Так а зачем вы указываете [0] после селектора? Это ведь и указывает, что взять только первый элемент массива. Попробуйте убрать квадратные скобки.  И в качестве селектора используйте класс ".spisok" а не ".container".

Comment: @mccrush данная библиотека возвращает результат в виде массива, даже если нашла всего один элемент. В качестве селектора я не использую .spisok потому что в коде может быть какой-нибудь ul.another-container, в котором так же будут .spisok элементы, и тогда поиск по селектору .spisok вернет объединенный список элементов из обоих ul.